How to assign traffic to a Google Analytics channel based on URL in GA4
I remember I was able to assign the channel groups via the final URL in earlier versions.
Right now, I do not find the option to do so anmyore.
I get traffic from my affiliate publishers, however they do NOT use the recommended utm-parameters.
The final URL (when they reach my shop) is setup like this:
https://www.myshop.com/?bid=273421-0-XXXXYYYZZ&affref=www.affilate.de

Now, I want to apply this simple logic:
IF URL contains "affreff"

--> assign to channel "affiliate".
How do I do that?

You cannot do this in GA4, the rules for defining channels can be chosen from:

Default channel group
Medium
Source
Source platform
Campaign ID
Campaign name

